# How do I create a template in facebook?

Tags: facebook

I cannot find the "create feed template" option on my applications page.

Do I need to authorize my application? I didnt do that yet and am able to allow the user to login and allow permissions etc.

I havent submitted my application as it says the app needs 5 people or 10 monthly users, I just created it and my iphone app isnt out yet?

If I get to the Test console on facebook I dont see my app in the drop down menu? I dont even see a drop down menu.

How Do I create a template? Did facebook change the layout again :P making these tutorials off point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea there's no such thing as templates anymore, you just pass the content as part of the api call.

Start here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish

Comment: thanks. I will take a look.

I currently have everything setup for the user to login and allow permission for status updates. How Do I just post a status update? I am not interested in wall posts to friends etc at the moment.

Comment: `stream.publish` can publish to your own wall (aka, a status update).

Comment: your own wall, meaning the logged in users wall? or my apps wall? My uses will want to publish to their own walls. :)

Comment: `stream.publish` can write entries on _walls_. Any wall that the current session has access to. If you read those docs (section called "Updating a User's Status" right near the top, for example) you'll notice if you simply supply the user you have logged in as the target it will end up on their wall. In order to post to your apps wall you would need to supply you app as the target.

Comment: I come to status.set, but there are no examples or anything. What is the difference between publish_stream permission and what I currently use dialog.permission = @"status_update";

even though I am not updating the status at the moment.

Comment: You've lost me. Where did you get `status.set` from? Just use `stream.publish` to update the users wall directly.

Comment: Just a different api to do the same thing. I always found `stream.publish` more explicit and convenient.